# What are the eightball rules when white ball and the eightball get stuck in the corner?

Tags: rules, pool

What happens when opponent still has balls left, and the eightball was my last ball?

The balls are stuck, meaning that when my opponent hits the white ball the eightball will fall into the pocket, losing him the game?

[image: Pool table with black and white balls wedged in jaws of pocket]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens when 2 balls partially fall into a pocket and then get stuck?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/18381/what-happens-when-2-balls-partially-fall-into-a-pocket-and-then-get-stuck)

Comment: Not really, firstly the balls are not "suspended in the air" in my situation, secondly if there was to be any pocketing of the balls, I would have lost as the eight ball would have to be pocketed as well as the white ball? There is no consensus in the other thread either.

Comment: In this situation, your opponent would probably not hit the white ball, because they don't want to lose the game. So they would intentionally not hit the white ball, which would be a scratch. Then you would hit the white ball to win the game, assuming you can hit the white ball in a way that it doesn't fall into the pocket, which would lose the game for you.